# TAM 2014: Get me your Questions

Tags: discussion, conference

As per [this post](https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2743/the-amazing-meeting-2014-sponsorship-proposal), I am heading to TAM. I will be [live tweeting](https://twitter.com/LarianLeQuella) the event like I have done for the past two years.  However, I would really like for you the skeptic community to contribute to TAM in your own way.  Basically, you can send a tweet to me [@LarianLeQuella](https://twitter.com/LarianLeQuella), or even [go to the TAM page](http://www.amazingmeeting.com/) and look at the speakers and come up with a question* that you can post here.

*Please note I said question, not comment, story, opinion, etc. Make it clear and consice. No quemments.

Answer (score 1):

I would personally love to see Randi and company explain why after 60 years of scientific research, the bee "waggle dance" theory is more widely accepted than the odor plume theory. Bees seem to have an almost mystical communication method that would qualify them for the [1 million dollar prize](http://www.randi.org/site/index.php/1m-challenge.html).

It is interesting that most other insects don't communicate through dance, but smell, so why the belief that bees are so different? We [still seem](http://www.utexas.edu/news/2010/12/13/biology_bees/) to be spending [research money](http://www.livescience.com/17395-honeybees-head-butts-decisions.html) that [entertains](http://jeb.biologists.org/content/215/12/2022.full.pdf) this theory.

> There are two main hypotheses to explain how foragers recruit other workers —the "waggle dance" or "dance language" theory and the "odor plume" theory. The dance language theory is far more widely accepted, and has far more empirical support.

My [question here](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/9023/do-bees-use-odor-instead-of-dance-to-communicate-the-location-of-food) hasn't drawn much attention.

Comment: Hmm, no sure where this would fit in to the question/answer sessions at the end of anyone's presentation. And I don't think anyone is going to be an insect expert that I personally know at TAM.  If I find anyone, I will direct them to your question though. :)

Comment: Unfortunately, I looked over the presenters and didn't see any biologists. The question is interesting to me because it deals with scientific dogma. I remember how long it took (and what lengths the doctor went to) to convince the medical community that ulcers were caused by a bacteria and not stress/smoking/etc.

Comment: This answer triggered me to have another look at that old question, and post an answer.